# How to group up commonly accessed files in a Project, and then show them in a simple fast accessible folder?

Tags: eclipse, treeview, project, directory-structure

When you are working with a project, you often need to **click many times** in the Tree view & search for files in different locations, just to get the desire files opened.

Is there a way to let some **commonly accessed files** directly shown under the root of the Project (or **group them up** in a **simple fast accessible folder**)?

eg: like creating virtual **Links** to those files under the root of the Project. (or other solutions).

---

This is what I am doing right now:

[image: demo]

the problem is::

1. manually creating the links in Windows are really time consuming. You can't just right click in Eclipse to create them.
2. - when you open them, they will be opened with `Default Editor` -- which treats them as `Text file` not `link file`.
   - you can open it with `System Editor`, but that

     - requires you to set all these file to be opened by `Eclipse.exe` in your operating system.

       maybe its fine for `.java` file, but for all other files (eg: `.xml`, `.html`) is probably not good.
     - you have to right click to open it everytime
3. the icons in the tree view becomes just a Text file icon.

Comment: You can, as alternatives, use Ctrl+Shift+R or set Bookmarks in the files.

Comment: @nitind (for `Ctrl+Shift+R`, it finds the file, but I still need to type the name.)
And for, the way `Bookmark` works, does not group up the files good enough in the way I want. 
It would be better if its a bit more organizable & able to be shown in the Tree view inside the Project -- as if its a folder.

Comment: Is [Mylyn's task-focused interface](https://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) what you are looking for? In the _Bookmark_ view you can't organize bookmarks into folders because nobody implements that yet. If you think that would be a helpful feature, please consider to implement and contribute it to Eclipse.

Comment: @howlger `Mylyn Task List` is interesting, I tried on it, 
It seems its able to store the perspective of the opening views of files when I create a `new Task` & `activate` it. 
And they are able to be stored in the `Task List` as a single task. 
The switching of tasks involves closing of the perspective of the files -- Its highly tied with what files you `have opened`.
Its good to know this feature. But its not quite what Im looking for. It seems to have a good use for some other cases.